# Python2.7 requests exception handling

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I am attempting to post an object to an http end point, this is my code:

```
try:
    response = requests.post(url, data=obj['message'], headers=headers)
    logger.warn("Not bad resp: %s" % (response))
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    logger.warn(str(e))
```

Bizarrely enough, I actually get a 200 response, but for some reason, the exception condition gets triggered. I know this as I used to output response code in the exception section, but since it was 200, and I wanted more context, I tried to play with the more advanced error handling, I tried a few things including this except like:

```
except requests.RequestException as e:
```

These logger lines:

```
logger.warn(e)
print(e)
```

Nothing seems to work.. I always fail with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/bin/lam_replay.py", line 190, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/python/bin/lam_replay.py", line 187, in main
    replayer(filename, moogsoft['hostname'])
  File "/opt/python/bin/lam_replay.py", line 92, in replayer
    response = requests.post(url, data=obj['message'], headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 108, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1041, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1075, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1037, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 885, in _send_output
    self.send(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 857, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 24781: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to fix exception encoding?? what am I missing ??

Comment: The argument `data` is supposed to be type `dict`. Check your type.

Comment: I am certainly sending a giant json object, thanks for the tip, will check.

Comment: I see. Stacktrace seem to refer to your dict having non-ascii characters. Try to encode manually `data=json.dumps(obj['message'], ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')`

Comment: I tried to check if object is type dict and it isnt, but it I output the object to a file and open in notepad++, I can get it to prettify with json formatter. Any other thoughts on this? I will try the endocing method too.

Answer (score 0):

As I read in line from file, I use the unicode function and set it to 'ignore errors'

```
    obj = unicode(f.readline(), errors='ignore')
    obj = json.loads(obj)
```

Then, I load the line as json. Instead of loading the line straight as json.